# Ambiguous use of functions (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, functional-programming, overloading, swift4

I've been trying to figure out why the following code is ambiguous...

```
public func product <T1: Sequence, T2: Sequence> (_ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2) ->
    AnySequence<(T1.Element, T2.Element)> {
  return AnySequence(
    sequence1.flatMap { element1 in
      sequence2.map { element2 in
        (element1, element2)
      }
    }
  )
}

public func product <T1: LazySequenceProtocol, T2: LazySequenceProtocol> (_ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2) ->
    LazySequence<AnySequence<(T1.Element, T2.Element)>> {
  return AnySequence(
    sequence1.flatMap { element1 in
      sequence2.map { element2 in
        (element1, element2)
      }
    }
  ).lazy
}
```

...when I call it with two lazy sequences and a call to `makeIterator`[<sup>EXAMPLE</sup>](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5992c919d4b80c61b7f2c490).

```
_ = product([1, 2].lazy, [3, 4].lazy).makeIterator()
```

Yet, the following code doesn't have this ambiguity...

```
public struct Product2Sequence <T1: Sequence, T2: Sequence>: Sequence {
  public typealias Element = (T1.Element, T2.Element)
  public typealias Iterator = AnyIterator<Element>

  private let iterator: Iterator

  internal init (_ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2) {
    self.iterator = AnyIterator(
      sequence1.flatMap { element1 in
        sequence2.map { element2 in
          (element1, element2)
        }
      }.makeIterator()
    )
  }

  public func makeIterator () -> Iterator {
    return self.iterator
  }
}

public struct LazyProduct2Sequence <T1: LazySequenceProtocol, T2: LazySequenceProtocol>: LazySequenceProtocol {
  public typealias Element = (T1.Element, T2.Element)
  public typealias Iterator = AnyIterator<Element>

  private let iterator: Iterator

  internal init (_ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2) {
    self.iterator = AnyIterator(
      sequence1.flatMap { element1 in
        sequence2.map { element2 in
          (element1, element2)
        }
      }.makeIterator()
    )
  }

  public func makeIterator () -> Iterator {
    return self.iterator
  }
}

public func product <T1: Sequence, T2: Sequence> (_ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2) -> Product2Sequence<T1, T2> {
  return Product2Sequence(sequence1, sequence2)
}

public func product <T1: LazySequenceProtocol, T2: LazySequenceProtocol> (_ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2) ->
    LazyProduct2Sequence<T1, T2> {
  return LazyProduct2Sequence(sequence1, sequence2)
}
```

...when I call it with two lazy sequences and a call to `makeIterator`[<sup>EXAMPLE</sup>](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5992cac0d4b80c61b7f2c492).

```
_ = product([1, 2].lazy, [3, 4].lazy).makeIterator()
```

My reasoning is that a lazy sequence conforms both to `LazySequenceProtocol` and `Sequence` so the type system doesn't know which `product` to choose. But by that definition the second version should also not work.

I'm using Swift 4.0.

**What makes the second version work?**

Comment: I can't tell you why, but `let p = product1([1, 2].lazy, [3, 4].lazy) ; let i = p.makeIterator()` compiles in both versions.

Comment: @SuperPlushBear What version of swift are you using?

Comment: @Mrwerdo: I'm using Swift 4.0.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you. Yes, I came to that conclusion earlier as well. This seems to be some weird edge case.

Comment: Did you ask at bugs.swift.org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that was resolved with 4.1 (see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4509). There used to be no way for the type solver to choose between `Sequence` and `LazySequenceProtocol`, as the former obviously conforms to the latter.

I can't say for sure why your second version does work with 4.0 and have no evidence to support my assumptions, but I would guess it has something to do with the type solver being able to get more information from more concrete return types.

Anyway, `LazySequenceProtocol` is now preferred so as to preserve laziness as long as possible. Your code works as expected with Swift 4.1.